# Multiple Declarations of [variable name]

Tags: c, header-files

I am working on a header file that does a couple of functions for me. I include the header file in two seperate files, the c file and the main file.

I use `#ifndef` and `#def` but it looks like it still gets compiled twice, because during the linking process I get serveral

> multiple declarations of ...

errors.

### PLL header file

```c
#ifndef PLL_HEADER
#define PLL_HEADER

/********************************************************************
 * includes
 ********************************************************************/
#include "board.h"
#include "pin_mux.h"
#include "clock_config.h"
#include "PITDriver.h"

// Some more stuff

#endif
```

### Here is the relevant log data

```
[compiling stuff]

Building target: PLL Function.axf
Invoking: MCU Linker

[other linker stuff]

./source/main.o:C:\Users\mailn\Desktop\Work\Sparton\MCUXPresso Workstation\PLL Function\Debug/../source/PLL.h:45: multiple definition of `accumulateVal'
./source/PLL.o:C:\Users\mailn\Desktop\Work\Sparton\MCUXPresso Workstation\PLL Function\Debug/../source/PLL.h:45: first defined here

./source/main.o:C:\Users\mailn\Desktop\Work\Sparton\MCUXPresso Workstation\PLL Function\Debug/../source/PLL.h:46: multiple definition of `getValOne'
./source/PLL.o:C:\Users\mailn\Desktop\Work\Sparton\MCUXPresso Workstation\PLL Function\Debug/../source/PLL.h:46: first defined here

./source/main.o:C:\Users\mailn\Desktop\Work\Sparton\MCUXPresso Workstation\PLL Function\Debug/../source/PLL.h:47: multiple definition of `getValTwo'
./source/PLL.o:C:\Users\mailn\Desktop\Work\Sparton\MCUXPresso Workstation\PLL Function\Debug/../source/PLL.h:47: first defined here

./source/main.o:C:\Users\mailn\Desktop\Work\Sparton\MCUXPresso Workstation\PLL Function\Debug/../source/PLL.h:48: multiple definition of `countTo'
./source/PLL.o:C:\Users\mailn\Desktop\Work\Sparton\MCUXPresso Workstation\PLL Function\Debug/../source/PLL.h:48: first defined here

./source/main.o:C:\Users\mailn\Desktop\Work\Sparton\MCUXPresso Workstation\PLL Function\Debug/../source/PLL.h:49: multiple definition of `runUntil'
./source/PLL.o:C:\Users\mailn\Desktop\Work\Sparton\MCUXPresso Workstation\PLL Function\Debug/../source/PLL.h:49: first defined here

./source/main.o:C:\Users\mailn\Desktop\Work\Sparton\MCUXPresso Workstation\PLL Function\Debug/../source/PLL.h:50: multiple definition of `currentValue'
./source/PLL.o:C:\Users\mailn\Desktop\Work\Sparton\MCUXPresso Workstation\PLL Function\Debug/../source/PLL.h:50: first defined here

collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [makefile:39: PLL Function.axf] Error 1
```

Comment: Looks like you probably have actual variables with storage located in your header file. Include guards don't protect against this. Put those variables in PLL.c and have `extern`-marked versions of those variable in the header. That way, both files can refer to the variable, but it only exists in one place.

Comment: Have you *implemented* the function in the header file itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correction made according to the comment of @Peter

In C you can only put variable definitions in a header if it is only included in one compilation unit.

You seem to have two compilation unit :

- one that compiles your PLL.h and PLL.c to create PLL.o
- one that compiles your main.c and PLL.h to create main.o

Both of your objects files contain the variables that you have defined in PLL.h and therefore when you hit the linker it throws an error because the variables have been declared twice (once in each object file).

To correct this error you can either change the way you compile to merge your two compilation unit. Or (if you use an IDE that handles automatically your compilation) you can apply the following changes to avoid defining the variable in your header.

In the header : (change the definition to a declaration)

```
extern int x;
```

In a source file : (define the variable)

```
int x;
```

Comment: It's not *forbidden* to have a variable definition in a header.   However, a header that defines a variable can ONLY be included in one compilation unit.   If it is included in two or more compilation units, that variable will be defined multiple times in the program.   (According to the standard that gives undefined behaviour but, practically, it typically results in "multiple definition" errors when linking).

Comment: Thank you for the correction, I wasn't aware of this, do you want to correct my answer or do you want me to do it ?